# iOS returns "null" data from JSON feed

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, null

I am downloading and parsing a JSON feed in my iOS application. Some parts of the data that the JSON feed provides are shown correctly in my iOS application, however some parts of the JSON feed seem to return "null" even though in the actual JSON feed itself, they do not contain the data "null".

Here is my code:

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];
NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"current_observation"];
NSArray *cur = [results valueForKey:@"weather"];
NSArray *loc = [results valueForKey:@"full"];
NSArray *tmp = [results valueForKey:tmptype];
```

The JSON feed I am trying to load is this one:
http://api.wunderground.com/api/595007cb79ada1b1/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json

One part of the JSON feed that returns "null" is:

```
"full":"San Francisco, CA"
```

The above returns "null".... why? And how do I go about fixing this issue?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: "The above returns "null"" - what you had above was a key-value pair. In what sense can it "return null" (whatever that means)?

Comment: Sorry my explanations poor, what I mean is that when I try to access the data that "full" contains via my iOS app, my app returns (displays) the string "null" instead of "San Francisco, CA".

Comment: How are you accessing the data?

Comment: How do you display it?  Are you performing logic prior to displaying the value such as any type of formatting?

Comment: No formatting, I am just fetching the data and passing it to a UILabel to display onscreen.

Comment: Looks like you are assigning that value to an array.  That seems questionable.

Comment: Not sure. Could it be because the comma is not escaped? Comma is part of the JSON syntax. Did you try validating your full JSON feed?

Comment: Actually , `full` is inside `display_location` and `observation_location` which is inside `current_observation` (from where you are trying to fetch `full`).

Comment: Yeah basically the issue was that the data I was trying to access was nested JSON, so I had to correct the path in my iOS app. @Bonnie answer explains what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
NSString *full= [[results valueForKey:@"display_location"] valueForKey:@"full"]];
```

because it is a nested JSON.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!!! Right, I am very new to JSON, so thanks for that and now I understand how to use nested JSON data.

Comment: Worked like a charm and helped fix all my other JSON issues I was having with nested JSON. :D

Comment: What about indexed subscript notation? `NSString *full = results[@"display_location"][@"full"];` is shorter and easier on the eyes, for the exact same result.

Answer (score 1):

First of the results are not of type `NSArray`.

When you are trying to get the value fo the key: `full` you are not in the correct path.
You are in `current_observation.full` but the key you want is in `current_observation.display_location.full`. Since the JSON is nested you will need go in to the correct path.

You can get the full path in one go:

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
NSString *weather = [res valueForKeyPath:@"current_observation.weather"];
NSString *cur = [res valueForKeyPath:@"current_observation.display_location.full"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];
NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"current_observation"];
NSArray *cur = [results valueForKey:@"weather"];
NSString *full= [[res valueForKey:@"display_location"] valueForKey:@"full"]];
NSArray *tmp = [results valueForKey:tmptype];
```

try this it may help you.